# ImageMagick PHP Docker version issue

Tags: php, docker, imagemagick, dockerfile

I have updated

```
FROM php:7.1.27-fpm
```

to

```
FROM php:7.1.33-fpm
```

Next command is in my docker file

```
RUN apt-get update imagemagick
```

it updates ImageMagick version from

> Version: ImageMagick 6.9.7-4

to

> Version: ImageMagick 6.9.10-23

**I don't want to update the ImageMagick version to 6.9.10-23 & also don't want to install specific version via wget.**

Any other solution? Is there any way from which I can install specific version of ImageMagick instead of using wget?

Comment: Imagemagick it's pecl exstension.

Answer (score 1):

```
apt-get update imagemagick
```

yields `E: The update command takes no argument`.

If you don't want to upgrade IM why are you running the command in the first place (or was that `apt-get install`)?

Anyway this isn't really an ImageMagick question, just a Docker packaging one. The PHP image is based on Debian, its authors assume that this version of PHP works well with the provided version of Apache and the provided version of ImageMagick (and the all-important underlying version of Glibc...).

Possible solutions

- Amend the [Dockerfile to build the image](https://github.com/docker-library/php) to produce an image more to your liking (but you will have to test that everything works together).
- Build your image using your previous `FROM php:7.1.27-fpm` and upgrade PHP on image.
- Get the .DEB of the required release of ImageMagick, and COPY it in the image and install from that .DEB

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have imagick installed here is Dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.1.27-fpm

RUN apt-get update

RUN apt-get install -y libmagickwand-dev 
RUN apt-get install -y imagemagick

RUN pecl install imagick
RUN docker-php-ext-enable imagick
```

no need for wget etc.

if you buld the image this way:

```
docker build --tag stackoverflow .
```

you can log into its shell this way:

```
docker run -it --rm --entrypoint="" stackoverflow /bin/bash
```

when you're logged into CLI issue a command to see if its is installed (should be called `imagick`) under `[PHP Modules]`

```
php -m
```

and issuing the command:

```
php -r "echo phpversion('imagick');"
```

will give you `imagick` extension number (at this moment gives 3.4.4)